# How to run lua ML model from Google Colab

Tags: lua, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run this [neural style transfer](https://github.com/jcjohnson/neural-style) model from Github but on Google Colab because my computer doesn't have enough memory/CPU/anything.

I have mounted my google drive to my notebook, cloned the repo onto my drive by following [this tutorial](https://lalorosas.com/blog/github-colab-drive) downloaded the models to my drive folder, and just to test that it works, I'm using the most basic example of running the Brad Pitt example in the readme using:

```
th neural_style.lua -style_image examples/inputs/picasso_selfport1907.jpg -content_image examples/inputs/brad_pitt.jpg
```

But for some reason it won't work.

1. Using `subprocess.run()` just returned `No such file or directory`
2. Using `!th neural_style.lua...` returns `th: command not found`

I've tried like four other things and they all give me a variant of the above two error messages. Any thoughts?

Here is the full notebook code to reproduce my setup on Colab from start to end/error:

```
# Mount the drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# Clone the repo onto the drive
!git clone https://github.com/jcjohnson/neural-style

# Install Pytorch
!pip3 install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu80/torch-0.3.0.post4-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl 
!pip3 install torchvision

# Download the models per the github repo instructions
!bash models/download_models.sh

!th neural_style.lua -style_image examples/inputs/picasso_selfport1907.jpg -content_image examples/inputs/brad_pitt.jpg
```

Answer (score 4):

First:

```
%cd /content/
!git clone https://github.com/nagadomi/distro.git torch --recursive
import os
os.chdir('./torch/')
!bash install-deps
!./install.sh
!. ./install/bin/torch-activate
```

Now it should work using absolute path to `th`:

```
!/content/torch/install/bin/th neural_style.lua -style_image examples/inputs/picasso_selfport1907.jpg -content_image examples/inputs/brad_pitt.jpg
```